# jinja get code back from parsed template

Tags: python, jinja2

I have following jinja template in variable *code*:

```
code = """{% set p1 = 'hello world' %}
          <p>{{p1}}</p>"""
```

I am getting parsed template using parse method,

```
from jinja2 import Environment
env = Environment()
template = env.parse(code)
```

now, how to get the original code back from the parsed template?